# How to upload files via FTPS using Rake::FtpUploader

Tags: ruby, ssl, ftp, rake

I want to upload a bunch of files and the Rake::FtpUploader seems to be a good choice for this.

So I have my `Rakefile`:

```
require "rake/contrib/ftptools"

task :upload do

 uploader = Rake::FtpUploader.new('/','mydomain.com','ftpuser', 'secret')
 uploader.upload_files('*.html')

end
```

It seems, that the server requires SSL:

```
Response:
550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel
```

Now I am not able to tell the `FtpUploader` that I would like to use SSL and when I change the line like so:

```
 uploader = Rake::FtpUploader.new('/','ftps://mydomain.com','ftpuser', 'secret')
```

I get the following output:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

**Update**: Changed url-scheme from `sftp` to `ftps`

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you are asking about, [SSH File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) or [FTP over SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS)? The URI scheme `sftp` and the question title suggest the former, the client you're using and the error you get suggest the latter. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @toro2k Thanks for pointing this out. I thought SFTP was FTP over SSL. I would like to use FTP not SSH

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

The error occurs when the DNS resolution fails. Check if you can curl the api url

I mean to say
`curl mydomain.com`

from the command line. Changing the DNS server  might help.

Comment: I think it is Rake::FTP that does not support `ftps://` for a host string. I know my host is expecting FTPS